# Query to show only unique records based on certain criteria in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am working on a database that is something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nfZL.png)

In the event a job number when both current week and previous week in the "sort" column happens, choose only the current week row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlh86.png)

The first or last function don't work here as the current week or previous week record can either be the first or last row of a particular job number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group on the job and select the max date:

```
Select [Job Number], Max([Order Date]), YourWeekFunction(Max([Order Date]))
From YourTable
Group By [Job Number]
```